# How to use High Clock Frequency using clock wizard (BuffPll) in xilinx for serial communication?

Tags: clock, xilinx

I wanted to develop a high speed data transmission serial communication protocol, for a adc/dac link using spartan 6 fpga programmed in xilinx ise (14.7), so I wanted to increase speed of internal clock (provided as spartan 6 has 100Mhz clock at peripheral) using clock wizard. I have a transmission protocol based on uart, I am able to receive data bits successfully for upto 405 Mhz using clock wizard, above that it is asking to use buffpll and implementing it, i am not able to recieve frames at reciever...

What could be the possible error and solution to it ?

I tried developing but the channel is not visible at reciever's side ...

Comment: please provide a more detailed explanation of the error and add additional information such as the specific error message, the context in which the error occurred, any relevant code snippets or logs , ...